# Conditionally Join the Table with a Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables. BaseProducts, Products and ProductsMerchants. I need to find the count using a condition. This is my SQL,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalProductsCount]
(
    @SuperUser bit,
    @MarchantId int
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@SuperUser = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM    [dbo].[BaseProducts]
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM    [dbo].[BaseProducts] BP
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] P ON P.BaseProductId = BP.Id
                INNER JOIN ProductsMerchants PM ON PM.ProductId = P.Id
        WHERE   PM.MarchantId = @MarchantId;
    END
END
```

The problem is that I need to rewrite the same query just for checking a condition. Can I make it one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM    [dbo].[BaseProducts]
WHERE @SuperUser = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM    [dbo].[BaseProducts] BP
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] P ON P.BaseProductId = BP.Id
        INNER JOIN ProductsMerchants PM ON PM.ProductId = P.Id
WHERE   PM.MarchantId = @MarchantId AND @SuperUser <> 1;
```

Personally, I find the `if` form more understandable.

If the `inner join`s are being used for filtering and don't increase the number of rows, you could also do:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM    [dbo].[BaseProducts] BP
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Products] P ON P.BaseProductId = BP.Id 
        LEFT JOIN ProductsMerchants PM ON PM.ProductId = P.Id
WHERE   PM.MarchantId = @MarchantId OR @SuperUser = 1;
```

(The `PM.MarchantId = @MarchantId` undoes the left outer join.)

But once again, I find that the intent of the `if` is clearer.

Or even this:

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN @SuperUser = 1 THEN CNT ELSE COUNT(*) END) AS Total
FROM    (SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT FROM [dbo].[BaseProducts] BP) const CROSS JOIN
         [dbo].[BaseProducts] BP
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] P ON P.BaseProductId = BP.Id
        INNER JOIN ProductsMerchants PM ON PM.ProductId = P.Id 
WHERE   PM.MarchantId = @MarchantId OR @SuperUser = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Which will be more efficient in terms of performance?

Comment: Which one will be efficient?

Comment: @user960567 . . . The first method with the `if`.  All the others essentially have to do all or some of the work for both answers.